# javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: 103.12.134.112, port: 25;

Tags: java

i am using java mail for sending the mail , i am stuck in this error: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: 103.12.134.112, port: 25;
i have see the related question , bt its not work for me , using window 8. help me  , thankx in advance.

```
package com.airportbookingvn;
    import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.util.Properties;





    import javax.activation.DataHandler;
    import javax.activation.DataSource;
    import javax.mail.Message;
    import javax.mail.Session;
    import javax.mail.Transport;
    import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
    import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
    import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
    import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;
    import javax.mail.util.ByteArrayDataSource;

    import com.lowagie.text.Chunk;
    import com.lowagie.text.Document;
    import com.lowagie.text.Paragraph;
    import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;



    /**
     * Email with PDF example.
     * <br><br>
     * Email sending code adapted from http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/javamail/how-to-send-an-email-with-a-file-attachment.html.
     * @author Jee Vang
     *
     */
    public class SendAttachment {

        /**
         * Sends an email with a PDF attachment.
         */
        public void email() {
            String smtpHost = "103.12.134.112"; //replace this with a valid host
            int smtpPort = 25; //replace this with a valid port

            String sender = "sender@yourhost.com"; //replace this with a valid sender email address
            String recipient = "recipient@anotherhost.com"; //replace this with a valid recipient email address
            String content = "dummy content"; //this will be the text of the email
            String subject = "dummy subject"; //this will be the subject of the email

            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHost);
            properties.put("mail.smtp.port", smtpPort);     
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, null);

            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = null;

            try {           
                //construct the text body part
                MimeBodyPart textBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                textBodyPart.setText(content);

                //now write the PDF content to the output stream
                outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                writePdf(outputStream);
                byte[] bytes = outputStream.toByteArray();

                //construct the pdf body part
                DataSource dataSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(bytes, "application/pdf");
                MimeBodyPart pdfBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                pdfBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(dataSource));
                pdfBodyPart.setFileName("test.pdf");

                //construct the mime multi part
                MimeMultipart mimeMultipart = new MimeMultipart();
                mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(textBodyPart);
                mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(pdfBodyPart);

                //create the sender/recipient addresses
                InternetAddress iaSender = new InternetAddress(sender);
                InternetAddress iaRecipient = new InternetAddress(recipient);

                //construct the mime message
                MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
                mimeMessage.setSender(iaSender);
                mimeMessage.setSubject(subject);
                mimeMessage.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, iaRecipient);
                mimeMessage.setContent(mimeMultipart);

                //send off the email
                Transport.send(mimeMessage);

                System.out.println("sent from " + sender + 
                        ", to " + recipient + 
                        "; server = " + smtpHost + ", port = " + smtpPort);         
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                //clean off
                if(null != outputStream) {
                    try { outputStream.close(); outputStream = null; }
                    catch(Exception ex) { }
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Writes the content of a PDF file (using iText API)
         * to the {@link OutputStream}.
         * @param outputStream {@link OutputStream}.
         * @throws Exception
         */
        public void writePdf(OutputStream outputStream) throws Exception {
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);

            document.open();

            document.addTitle("Test PDF");
            document.addSubject("Testing email PDF");
            document.addKeywords("iText, email");
            document.addAuthor("Jee Vang");
            document.addCreator("Jee Vang");

            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
            paragraph.add(new Chunk("hello!"));
            document.add(paragraph);

            document.close();
        }

        /**
         * Main method.
         * @param args No args required.
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SendAttachment demo = new SendAttachment();
            demo.email();
        }
    }
```

---

```
    ERROR :
    javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: 103.12.134.112, port: 25;
      nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1706)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:525)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:291)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:172)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:121)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:190)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:120)
        at com.airportbookingvn.SendAttachment.email(SendAttachment.java:89)
        at com.airportbookingvn.SendAttachment.main(SendAttachment.java:136)
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:284)
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:227)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1672)
        ... 8 more
```

Comment: That is a network issue more than a programming issue. Make sure the smtp server you are trying to contact is in fact answering on that IP address and port. If the server is external and you are using a proxy, traffic on port 25 may be blocked as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is no smtp server listening at 103.12.134.112 port 25 at the moment (I just checked)

You can check using telnet. See answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11988455/3536342 by balanv for more information.

Comment: As your suggestion , i run telnet smtp.mydomain.com 25 , i got this error in command prompt :Connecting To smtp.mydomain.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port
 25: Connect failed..