# My PHP Upload Form Works But No Email Received

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload, webforms

Could somebody please take a look at this extremely simple php file upload form and tell me what I am doing wrong, it all works fine on the website, even recieving the confirmation message. However no email is being recieved at my email address. This is my first attempt at a PHP form.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //The form has been submitted, prep a nice thank you message
    $output = '<h1>Your Application Has Been Received</h1>';
    //Set the form flag to no display (cheap way!)
    $flags = 'style="display:none;"';

    //Deal with the email
    $to = 'myemail.com';
    $subject = 'Application';

    $message = strip_tags($_POST['message']);
    $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])));
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];

    $boundary =md5(date('r', time())); 

    $headers = "From: myemail.com\r\nReply-To:   myemail.com";
    $headers .= "\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed;   boundary=\"_1_$boundary\"";

    $message="This is a multi-part message in MIME format.


--_1_$boundary
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"_2_$boundary\"

--_2_$boundary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

$message

--_2_$boundary--
--_1_$boundary
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"$filename\" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
Content-Disposition: attachment 

$attachment
--_1_$boundary--";

    mail($to, $subject, $name, $email, $headers);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>MailFile</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php echo $output; ?>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post" <?php echo $flags;?>>
<label for="name">Name</label><input type="name" name="name" id="name"></p>
<p>
<label for="phone">Telephone</label> <input type="phone" name="phone" id="phone"></p>
<p> 
<label for="email">Email</label> <input type="email" name="email" id="email"></p>
<p>
<label for="message">Cover Note</label> <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="20" rows="8">  </textarea></p>
<p><label for="file">File</label> <input type="file" name="file" id="file"></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="send"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

***UPDATE***

The form is working but only the Cover Note is being recieved, why are the other fields not sending by email?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and download PHPMailer. It will do everything you want and eliminate your headaches.

Comment: You have SMTP service running where you are testing this code?

Comment: yes, it was on the web page which it was going to stay on. The website is actually a design website, however the web designer is unable to do it so it has fallen to me!

Comment: @yajakass would you like a live link to the site?

Comment: I can't check from the site if SMTP is running or not.

Comment: could you explain to me what you mean? @yajakass

Comment: Well to send email you need SMTP service running, so when you call `mail()` function in php it talks to SMTP port(default 25) to send the mail. You can check it on your server. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988454/how-to-check-if-smtp-is-working-from-commandline-linux

Comment: SMTP is running @yajakass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

- You're passing the wrong arguments to [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). This line:

  ```
  mail($to, $subject, $name, $email, $headers);
  ```

  should be:

  ```
  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
  ```
- You're not storing all the form fields:

  You need to retrieve all the form fields from `$_POST` and incorporate them into your message. Perhaps something along these lines:

  ```
  $message  = "Name: " . $_POST['name'] . "\n";
  $message .= "Phone: " . $_POST['phone'] . "\n";
  $message .= "Email: " . $_POST['email'] . "\n";
  $message .= "Message:\n\n" . strip_tags($_POST['message']);
  ```
- Personally I would check the file type against a white-list, and only use `application/octet-stream` for unknown types. For example:

  ```
  $type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
  if (!in_array ($type, array ('text/plain', 'image/png', 'audio/wav'))) {
    $type = 'application/octet-stream';
  }
  ```

  And then set `Content-Type: $type; name="$filename"` in the message body.