# Centos webpanel SMTP

Tags: php, centos, smtp, centos7, vps

I have installed centos web panel and have set up all things. there have two sites hosted. When I try to send email using PHPmailer. there has an error.

```
2018-09-20 15:15:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2018-09-20 15:15:10 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-vps203527.vps.ovh.ca250-PIPELINING250-SIZE 204800000250-ETRN250-STARTTLS250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-8BITMIME250 DSN
2018-09-20 15:15:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2018-09-20 15:15:11 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2018-09-20 15:15:11 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2018-09-20 15:15:11 
2018-09-20 15:15:11 
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2018-09-20 15:15:10 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 vps203527.vps.ovh.ca ESMTP Postfix

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'vps203527.vps.ovh.ca';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'admin@  .com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = '';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = false;                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 25;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('admin@.com', 'Test Mail');
    $mail->addAddress('@gmail.com', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient

    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

This is the php code i using

Comment: There isn't enough in your post to help you but there may be an answer to your error in this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477766/phpmailer-smtp-error-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host

Comment: what details need to help

Comment: What PHP are you using, besides PHPMailer?

Comment: yes sorry spelling mistake. its PHPMailer. php version 7.2.4

Comment: Ok, so what variables are you sending to PHPMailer?

Comment: Also, check that SMTP is working: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988454/how-to-check-if-smtp-is-working-from-commandline-linux

Comment: I could be wrong but your mail host setting ($mail->Host = 'vps203527.vps.ovh.ca'; ) looks a bit strange. The username also ($mail->Username = 'admin@  .com')

Answer (score 1):

You are facing the issue because you have entered incorrect host value in your PHP script. Please enter your SMTP servers name in the host field [$mail->Host = 'vps203527.vps.ovh.ca';]. It should be like mail.yourdomainname.com

I also faced the same error and I fixed it by using the following code.

Following is the sample code to send email from your PHP script with SMTP authentication:

```
<?php
require("class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();                                // send via SMTP
$mail->Host     = "smtp.domain.com"; // SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "email@domain.com";   // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "password"; // SMTP password

$mail->From     = "email@domain.com";
$mail->FromName = "Name";
$mail->AddAddress("Recipient@emailaddress.com","Name");
$mail->AddReplyTo("yourname@domain.com","Your Name");

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                 // set word wrap

$mail->IsHTML(true);                               // send as HTML

$mail->Subject  =  "Here is the subject";
$mail->Body     =  "This is the <b>HTML body</b>";
$mail->AltBody  =  "This is the text-only body";

if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo "Message was not sent <p>";
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo "Message has been sent";

?>

Please make sure that you make the changes in the above script as necessary. 

Note: You should always verify the email address before sending an email campaign.
```

Please let me know if you face any issue. I will try to fix it.

Thank you!